# Using date field comparisons in RavenDB LINQ queries

Tags: c#, linq, nosql, ravendb

In RavenDB, I would like to query the database using a date field. How can I write a LINQ query to query the RavenDB that involves date comparison..

```
Session.Query<Movie>()
.Where(x => x.Status == "New" && x.ReleaseDate > DateTime.Parse("04/03/2012 00:00:00"))
.Dump();
```

is returning zero records inm LINQ pad. Something is not right the way I wrote the query.. thanks for any help.

Comment: Kind of obvious question here, are you able to return results if you exclude the date comparison from your query?

Comment: ZVenue, that query should work. You probably have another problem.

Comment: What happens if you add `WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow()` to the call, RavenDB indexes can be stale.

Comment: Also, what does `Session.Query<Movie>()
.Where(x => x.Status == "New" && x.ReleaseDate > DateTime.Parse("04/03/2012 00:00:00")).ToString()` show?

Comment: Stale results issue. It worked after adding WaitForNonStale... thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of DateTime.Parse() try instantiating a new DateTime.

```
Session.Query<Movie>()
.Where(x => x.Status == "New" && x.ReleaseDate > new DateTime(2012, 4, 3))
.Dump();
```

Comment: Why is this marked as the accepted answer? ZVenue should provide an answer to his own question describing the WFNSRAON method and choose that one as accepted.